# CANVAS or Flash based Treemap for 100,000s of Records

Tags: actionscript-3, canvas, d3.js, data-visualization

I have made a treemap using D3, but ran into trouble when i discovered that rendering more than 10,000 SVG-RECT/DIV was resulting in a perfomance lag/ browser hang. Also earlier posts have suggested Pre rendering D3, but that will not solve the problem of humongous amount of elements, and D3 isn't suitable for such a large volume of data.

I need to render 100,000 records at least, so as other options i have found ActionScript/MXML based libraries like AXIIS/Degrafa/Perfuse and some CANVAS based solutions.

Knowing that ActionScript has a steep learning curve in comparison to CANVAS, Between then which will be a better solution in the long run ?

Comment: You need to a) break it down in async blocks to avoid blocking UI (optionally web workers, but from web worker you won't have access to DOM), b) render it off-screen, push to DOM/onscreen canvas only when needed/ready. Flash/AS is "dying", go with canvas or SVG...

Comment: Thanks @KenFyrstenberg, since i can render it off screen, will pre rendering on the server using node.js and jsdom, also take care of my huge data issue because i dont need to really transfer the data ?

Comment: Compared to SVG or Canvas Flash Stage3D would chew this up with no problems. There is a steep learning curve there but if you look for a library that uses Stage3D, such as Starling, you might have good luck. (PS Flash/AS is not dying.)